# mysql_select_db returns false

Tags: php, mysql

There was a working website, but today I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'userName'@'' to database 'databaseName'
```

It doesn't show hostname. Why?

I am sure mysql_pconnect works correctly, but mysql_select_db doesnot.

```
function connect() {
    $this->connectionID=mysql_pconnect($this->server.(!empty($this->post) ? ":".$this->post : ""), $this->username, $this->password);
    if ($this->connectionID === false) {
        exit("Core module error: mysql error: ".mysql_error($this->connectionID));
    }

    if (mysql_set_charset("utf8", $this->connectionID) !== true) {
        // Windows bug detected: can't initaliaze charset cp1251, try to force setup
        $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->connectionID);
        $this->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $this->connectionID);
        $this->query("SET @@collation_connection = utf8_general_ci", $this->connectionID);
    }

    if (mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->connectionID) === false) {
//error is here
        exit("Core module error: mysql error: ".mysql_error($this->connectionID));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The message is clear: your web server is being denied access because it's using the wrong credentials. Have you changed something? Has your ISP?

Comment: first of all, you don't use mysql anymore, use `mysqli` or `pdo`. 

Your username && password is wrong.

Comment: I didn't. Waiting for an answer from ISP. mysql_pconnect is using correct credentials (same credentials uses mysql_select_db)

Comment: Well, I would like to use PDO, but just now it is impossible :( and I checked username and password, they are correct.

Comment: userName has no permission to access that db

Comment: Jaykishan, when I use phpmyadmin, userName has permission to access that db.

Comment: Ok, it was strange problem of ISP. Solved.